# Material UI react select value is not clearing on backspace

Tags: material-ui, react-select

After selecting option from dropdown. Value is not clearing on backspace.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nnvrz6px6l.

Any help is greatly appreciable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue it appears you now need to add the `isClearable={true}` prop to the `Select`. After adding this prop you can now clear the selected item with the backspace and a small `x` also appears to allow clearing the selected item.